# How to set the colors of a Window's pixels with Windows API (C++) once created?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am entirely new to Windows API, is there a direct method to change the pixels colors of a newly created Window ?

Comment: Thanks I'm looking for something like that but with relative coordinates to an existing Windows (so it should have a HWND argument).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

To change the color of single pixel at specific coordinates you can use SetPixel.

To change entire window background, you need to create a brush with specific color and assign it to the WNDCLASS structure's hbrBackground

HBRUSH hbr = ::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(240,230,240));
wc.hbrBackground = hbr;

However, for better get some understanding of GDI and related info, read some good tutorial or winapi book. A starting point could be
http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson17.htm

---

After having seen the comments above;

Following code draws anywhere on the screen

```
    // Draw a 100 x 100 pixel area with black
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        SetPixel(hdc, x+100, y+100, RGB(0, 0, 0));

ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

This works for me. Using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013.